# How to make <td> in new line

Tags: html, html-table

I have created dynamic Table with one `<tr>` and two `<td>` and want to keep each `<td>` in new line.

i.e.

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>Name:</td>
      <td>XYZ</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

this would display something like below

1)Name: - this should be in one line

2)XYZ - this should be in new line

Is is possible? how?

Comment: Define one <tr> for each line, but you probably don't even need tables for that. Just us <li> items.

Answer (score 3):

Add a tr:

```
<table> 
<tr>
  <td>Name:</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
   <td>XYZ</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that by using `<td>`.
A `<tr>` means table row, and until it gets closed the things you define in it will come in that row.

So, if you need to have a new line you should use a new `<tr>`

Or use `<ul>` and `<li>` wisely to attain your result instead of using tables

Answer (score 2):

Than make use of TR Not TD

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>Name:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>XYZ</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make two table rows (`<tr>`)...

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to using CSS, you can use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) ([Here's another guide I always use from CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)) by changing the direction to column (`flex-direction:column`) for the table row (`<tr>`).

```css
table tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

table tr td:first-child {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td>XYZ</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```